# Find all combinations of numbers from an array to reach the given sum

Tags: vb.net, sum

I am learning **vb.net** so I searched a lot about this but I could not find a solution.

I have the array:

```
{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536}
```

As can be seen, it is a following `2^n` sequence.

How can I get all arrays that the sum match with given value in a OPTIMIZED way?

Examples:

1. Sum: 64 -> Result: {64}
2. Sum: 80 -> Result: {16, 64} or {64, 16} (only one of these arrays)
3. Sum: 162 -> Result: {128, 32, 2}

Comment: in an optimized way? How can I understand it. Do you already have a solution which you think could be optimized? If you then post your code!

Comment: @MarcoSadowski Sorry if I was not clear. I found some in C# and converted to vb.net but as I want access this array every time (100 ms) I thought it might bring me problems depending on how it was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function to get a `Integer` array with all numbers of the sequence:

```
'function
Private Function GetNumbers(ByVal sumValue As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim seqNumbers As Integer() = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536}
    Dim seqNumbersInSum As New ArrayList

    'run through all numbers of the sequence.
    For seqIndex As Integer = UBound(seqNumbers) To 0 Step -1

        'don't use numbers of the sequence larger than the current sum value.
        If seqNumbers(seqIndex) > sumValue Then
            Continue For
        End If

        'subtract the current sequence number from sum value. Also add the used sequence number to the array list of used sequence numbers.
        sumValue -= seqNumbers(seqIndex)
        seqNumbersInSum.Add(seqNumbers(seqIndex))

        'in case the sum the result is 0 all sequence numbers are found.
        If sumValue = 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'return the used sequence numbers.
    Return seqNumbersInSum.ToArray(GetType(Integer))
End Function

'usage
GetNumbers(162) ' {128, 32, 2}
GetNumbers(80)  ' {64, 16}
GetNumbers(64)  ' {64}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to convert your number to its binary representation with [Convert.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_) (specifying base 2 for binary).  Then simply walk the string and for each "1" encountered, compute the equivalent base 2 power based on the current position.  This approach doesn't require a hard-coded array for the powers of 2:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim values() As Integer = {64, 80, 162}
    For Each value As Integer In values
        Dim powers As List(Of Integer) = GetBinaryPowers(value)
        Debug.Print(value & ": " & String.Join(", ", powers))
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetBinaryPowers(ByVal number As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim powers As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim strBinary As String = Convert.ToString(number, 2)
    For i As Integer = 0 To strBinary.Length - 1
        If strBinary(i) = "1" Then
            powers.Add(Math.Pow(2, strBinary.Length - (i + 1)))
        End If
    Next
    Return powers
End Function
```

Output:

```
64: 64
80: 64, 16
162: 128, 32, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim number As Int64 = 162
Dim factor As Integer = 0
Dim power As Int64
Dim numbers As New List(Of Int64)
Do
    power = 2 ^ factor
    If power > number Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    If (number And power) = power Then
        numbers.Add(power)
    End If

    factor += 1
Loop
```